# complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Find the residue of the function $f(z) = z/ (8-z^3)$ at $z = 2.$
I tried with the formula $\lim_{z\rightarrow a} \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \frac{ d^{m-1}}{ dz^{m-1}} (z-a)^m f(z)$. but it becomes very tedious. does it have any other formula for calculating these types of functions?

Comment: Tedious? I don't see it tedious at all... Anyway: another way is to express $f$ as Power series at $z=2$, and then read the $a_{-1}$ coefficient.. but I suppose this is not really faster

Comment: $m=1$ in your case, so it's not that tedious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may just start with
$$
f(z):=\frac{z}{8-z^3}=\frac{z}{2^3-z^3}=\frac{z}{(2-z)(4+2z+z^2)}
$$ giving, as $z \to 2$,

> $$
> (z-2)f(z)=-\frac{z}{4+2z+z^2} \to \color{red}{-\frac16}.
> $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(z)=8-z^3$ and $z_0=2$. Then it holds that $g(z_0)=0$ and $g'(z_0)\neq 0$ as well as $z\mapsto z$ being holomorphic. Thus we can apply

$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=z_0}\left(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right)=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}.$$

For your problem you get

$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=2}\left(\frac{z}{8-z^3}\right)=\frac{2}{-3\cdot 2^2}=-\frac{1}{6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{\mathcal{R} \equiv \braces{w\ \mid\ w^{3} = 8}}$:
\begin{align}
{z \over 8 - z^{3}} & =
-z\pars{{1 \over 24}\sum_{r\ \in\ \mathcal{R}}{r \over z - r}} =
-\,{1 \over 24}\sum_{r\ \in\ \mathcal{R}}{z\,r \over z - r}
\end{align}

Then, $\ds{-\,{1 \over 24}\,2\times 2 = \color{#f00}{-\,{1 \over 6}}}$.